# Collapsible entries

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Here is what I am trying to go.

We have a form where our guys in the production area here at a manufacturing plant fill out a form if they need a tool called a gage.  Our gage guy then takes the information and files it away.  I am trying to make this a form on our company intranet but am having a little trouble making it how they want, not a big deal they will live with whatever I give them.

Basically this will work as about 25 entries.  They will type in what they want and a form will be emailed to our gage guy, simple enough.  What I am trying to do is create a table with 25 entries but are not visible at page load, only the first one is.  Once a user begins typing in row one I would like row 2 to appear and so on and so forth.  Is something like this possible?

I have built the table for the most part but not with all 25 entries, only 5 for testing purposes.

Here is my table:

```
    <tr id="gage1">
      <th width="38" scope="row">1</th>
    <td width="346"><asp:TextBox ID="gage1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="gage2">
    <th scope="row">2</th>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="gage2"></asp:TextBox></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="gage3">
    <th scope="row">3</th>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="gage3" ></asp:TextBox></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="gage4">
    <th scope="row">4</th>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="gage3" ></asp:TextBox></td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="gage5">
      <th scope="row">5</th>
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="gage4" ></asp:TextBox></td>
  </tr>
    </table>
```

So at first load gage1 is visible.  When text is entered into gage1 asp box then gage2 becomes visible.  If I cant get it this way then I will just make an arrow next to each one that will collapse another row of the table but was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: I would do this with javascript and create a text listener of sorts on these boxes to adjust visibility on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this a long time ago sorry.  I make 20 lines and added a + button that when pressed would look at the lines to see if data were in them and if so would add another line.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a jQuery change event to the text boxes.

```js
$('#gageTable input').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next().show();
});
```

If you want the page load to show all the ones that have already been entered:

```js
$(document).load(function () {
    $('#gageTable input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            tr.show();
            tr.next().show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: For this answer to work, you'd want to default the display of all the rows except the first to "none"